# Which ssh/sshd config item will affect "Offering RSA public key"?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

All servers support the ssh public key authentication only in my environment. When I read the ssh debug info, I notice the "Offering RSA public key" is different.

When I ssh server1 from host1

```
user@host1:~$ ssh -v server1
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/online.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

However, when I ssh to server2 from host2

```
user@host2:$ ssh -v server2
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: jumpbox    <-- even not a file
```

Which ssh/sshd config item will affect the RSA public key offering method?
Unlucky, the server1 and server2 are in isolated networks, so I can't ssh server2 from host1 or ssh server1 from host2 to eliminate some factors.

Answer (score 1):

That should be the `~/.ssh/config` file on your machine. It should contain a section for server2 with an option for the identity file.

Comment: Nope, the `~/.ssh/config` only contains 2 lines `Host host2` and `user user` in host2, and `~/.ssh/config` is an empty file in host1.

Comment: check /etc/ssh/ssh_config on host2